# What British TV series featured characters fighting over an alligator doll?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I recall watching a British TV series in 2012. Here are the details:

- The main character was a clown who performed at birthday parties.
- There was another clown, who stole the main character's name.
- Another character was an old, rich, and blind man, who lived in a mansion.
- The old man had a giant collection of Beanie Babies in a huge vault.
- There were also two twin sisters, each missing one eye.
- The characters all wanted to get an alligator Beanie Baby doll that had survived a plane crash.
- Both the old man and the twin sisters sold their eyes to buy the doll.
- I believe the series was a sequel to another earlier British series.

Does anyone know the name of the series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Psychoville](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1305562/), a BBC TV series created by Reece Shearsmith and Steve Pemberton (two of the creators of *The League of Gentlemen*)

**The main character was a clown who performed at birthday parties.**

Mr Jelly

**There was another clown, who stole the main character's name.**

Mr Jolly

**Another character was an old, rich, and blind man, who lived in a mansion.**

Oscar Lomax

**There were also two twin sisters, each missing one eye.**

The Crabtree Sisters

**The characters all wanted to get an alligator Beanie Baby doll that had survived a plane crash.
Both the old man and the twin sisters sold their eyes to buy the doll.**

> Lomax only needs one more item to complete his collection, Snappy the
>   Crocodile. He once discovered it online, but two more people, the
>   Crabtree sisters (conjoined twins from Braintree, Essex) bought it
>   before him. Lomax bought Snappy from the sisters in exchange for his
>   eyes.

**I believe the series was a sequel to another earlier British series.**

Not really a sequal, but I suspect you are thinking of *The League of Gentlemen*

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoville) and [BBC page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00vw45s).

Wikipedia summary:

> The series revolves around five different characters from different
>   parts of England: David Sowerbutts (played by Pemberton), a serial
>   killer-obsessed man-child who still lives with his mother Maureen
>   (Shearsmith); Mr. Jelly (Shearsmith), an embittered one-handed
>   children's entertainer; Oscar Lomax (Pemberton), a blind millionaire
>   who collects stuffed toy animals; Joy Aston (French), a midwife who
>   treats a practice doll as if it is her real child; and Robert
>   Greenspan (Tompkins), a panto dwarf in love with his Snow White who
>   believes he has the power of telekinesis. All five are connected by a
>   mysterious blackmailer who has sent them a letter each with the
>   message: "I know what you did". The series is named after the title
>   given to The League of Gentlemen when the series was sold to Japan and
>   Korea.